# can't resolve this error: Javascript error ',' expected

Tags: javascript, next.js, jsx

I have an error on this array.map() and i can't figure what is the problem

```
const Websiteviewer = ({ web, content, styles, design }) => {



const test = ['1' , '2']
  return (
      {test.map(item => {
        console.log(item);
      } )}
  ) 
}

export default Websiteviewer
```

this is the react component and i have this following error ->

> [{    "resource": "/c:/path/WebsiteViewer.js",    "owner": "typescript",
> "code": "1005",     "severity": 8,  "message": "',' expected.",
> "source": "ts",     "startLineNumber": 18,  "startColumn": 12,
> "endLineNumber": 18,    "endColumn": 13 }]

[image of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CnMb5.png)

if you have any idea how to solve this.
thanks

Comment: You can only write JSX in JSX files

Comment: you're returning an object (inside statement parentheses, which are entirely unnecessary here, becaue they do nothing). Objects are specified as `{ key: value }` and you've used `{ value }`, so the error is saying "I expected a `:` here and your code has a `.`, please fix that because this is illegal syntax at the moment".

Comment: As JSX, you'd directly `items.map(...)`, without the curly braces around it at all, which in this case is the exact same solution as for plain JS (albeit for differens reasons).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not a good practice to log value inside JSX syntax. But you can prevent from your syntax error like this

```
const Websiteviewer = ({ web, content, styles, design }) => {
  const test = ["1", "2"];
  return (
    <>
      {test.map((item) => {
        console.log(item);
      })}
    </>
  );
};

export default Websiteviewer
```

Answer (score 0):

Return your item inside a fragment or a div since you can only return JSX in JSX files.Logging value inside return of JSX is a bad approach though.

```
const Websiteviewer = ({ web, content, styles, design }) => {
  const test = ["1", "2"];
  return (
    <>
      {test.map((item) => {
        console.log(item);
      })}
    </>
  );
};

export default Websiteviewer
```